# Accessing a segment of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have data

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
ind = np.array([0,1,4])
beg = 3
```

Typical size of `A` and `ind` is few millions.

What I want to do is modify data in `A` with index `ind+beg`.

```
for i in range(0,ind.size):
    A[ind[i]+beg] += 1
```

Since the operation on `A` (`+1`) is almost the same as adding `beg` to `ind[i]`,
I want to avoid this.

In C-code, I usually do this by using pointer.

```
int* ptA = A-beg;
for(int i=0; i<indsize; i++) ptA[ind[i]]++;
```

Is it possible to do in python in a similar way, or should I stick to the first code?

Answer (score 4):

I think the equivalent of your `C` approach is : `A[beg:][ind]+=1`, it saves some additions.   `add.at` is an unbuffered version, needed if `ind` have 
repeated values. it's generally slower.

```
A=arange(10010)
ind=np.unique(randint(0,10000,1000))
beg = 3

In [236]: %timeit for i in range(0,ind.size): A[ind[i]+beg] += 1
3.01 ms ± 313 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [237]: %timeit A[beg+ind]+=1
39.8 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [238]: %timeit A[beg:][ind]+=1
33.3 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [239]: %timeit add.at(A[beg:],ind,1)
151 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

`Numba` or `Cython` can speed this operation furthermore:

```
@numba.njit
def addat(A,beg,ind,amount):
    u=A[beg:]
    for i in ind:
        u[i]+=amount

In [249]: %timeit addat(A,beg,ind,1)
3.13 µs ± 688 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Surprisingly, upon testing this myself this does seem to be the fastest answer! I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has powerful indexing features, which are documented here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

In your case you can do:

```
>>> A[ind+beg] += 1
```

This will add `beg` to each member of `ind`, then will index into `A` at those locations and increment.